# What is wrong in Method $3$?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, contest-math

> Let $z,w$ be complex numbers such that $\bar z+i\bar w=0$ and $\arg(zw)=\pi$, find $\arg(z)$

**Method $1:$**

$\bar z=-i\bar w\implies z=iw$

Also, $\arg z+\arg w=\pi\implies\arg z+\arg\frac zi=\pi$

Therefore, $2\arg z-\frac\pi2=\pi\implies\arg z=\frac{3\pi}4 $

**Method $2:$**

$zw=-k, k\gt0$

Also, $w=\frac zi$

Therefore, $z^2=-ik$

It means, $\arg z^2=\frac{3\pi}2$

Therefore, $\arg z=\frac{3\pi}4$

**Method $3:$**

Let $z=x+iy, w=a+ib$

Given, $\bar z+i\bar w=0\implies x-iy+i(a-ib)=0$

Therefore, $x=-b, y=a$

Also, $\arg(zw)=\pi\implies\arg(x+iy)(a+ib)=\pi$

It means, $\arg (ax-by+i(bx+ay))=\pi$

Therefore, $\tan\pi=\frac{bx+ay}{ax-by}\implies ay=-bx$

Putting $b=-x, a=y,$ I get, $y^2=x^2$

Therefore, $y=x$ or $y=-x$

$y=x$ gives $\frac{\pi}4$. Is this incorrect? If yes, how to eliminate this?

Comment: You established necessary conditions , but not sufficient ones.

Comment: Saying $bx+ay=0$ only says that the argument is either $0$ or $\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(After reading the comments)

I got $\arg (ax-by+i(bx+ay))=\pi$

Putting $b=-x, a=y,$ I get, $$\arg(2xy+i(y^2-x^2))=\pi$$

Making $x^2=y^2$ could mean the argument is zero or $\pi$.

For it to be necessarily $\pi$, $2xy$ should be negative i.e. $x,y$ are of opposite sign.

Therefore, the answer is $\frac{3\pi}4$ and not $\frac\pi4$